# Detail on C vs. CP violation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, parity, cp-violation, charge-conjugation

In the answer given by knzhou to the post  [What distinguishes the behaviour of particle from its antiparticle: C violation or CP violation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410881/) it is said that

> "but the reaction $i \rightarrow f$ will run at the same rate as its $CP$ conjugate $\bar{f}_P \rightarrow \bar{i}_P$."

My questions is: is not $\bar{f}_P \rightarrow \bar{i}_P$ the $CT$ of $i \rightarrow f$ instead of its $CP$ conjugate since you have the anti-$f$ particles in the initial state?

---

**EDIT** I found something else that I do not understand. Why does knzhou say that C is not enough? If C distingishes particles and antiparticles and our theory violates C (not necessarily CP), the reactions $i\rightarrow f$ and its C conjugate $\bar{i} \rightarrow \bar{f}$ will have different rate since $i, f$ and its counterparts $\bar{i}, \bar{f}$ are different, so why do we need CP and not just C?

Moreover, if CPT is preserved but we look for CP violation, does it imply that T is not preserved? But is it not T a symmetry usually?

Comment: The f->i reaction should be the other way around to be CP conjugated... that shown reaction would be the CPT conjugated.

Comment: Sorry, I just made a mistake there, thanks for the catch!

Comment: @knzhou I have another question related to that post so I edited mine. If you could answer it I'd appreciate it

Comment: It's simply that if $i \to f$ converts, say, matter to antimatter at some rate, then $\tilde{i}_P \to \tilde{f}_P$ would convert it right back, giving no net change.

Comment: @knzhou Yeah, but why do you need to include parity? With C you have already that unbalance effect since your theory would not be C-even

Comment: @Vicky Unfortunately I'm not really sure what you mean, can you edit your post to explain in more detail?

Comment: @knzhou already done, better that way?

Comment: Possibly useful mnemonic: for *one* generation of left handed leptons and right-handed antileptons, the term $W_\mu^+\overline{\nu_L}\gamma^\mu e_L + W_\mu^-\overline{e_L}\gamma^\mu \nu_L$ is CPT , CP, and T invariant, but *not* P or C invariant.